ProviderNotFoundException in Flutter when using Provider with Cart and BalanceNotifier
I have been struggling with an issue for a few weeks now and can't seem to resolve it. I'm working on a Flutter application that uses the provider package for state management. I'm encountering a ProviderNotFoundException when trying to access my BalanceNotifier provider.
Error Message:

The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown while handling a gesture:

Error: Could not find the correct Provider<BalanceNotifier> above this Builder Widget

This happens because you used a BuildContext that does not include the provider.
My main.dart.
Future<void> handleUserLogin() async {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (user == null) {
    runApp(const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: AuthPage(), 
    ));
    return;
  }

  
  DocumentSnapshot doc =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();

  var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;
  if (data == null || !data.containsKey('userId')) {
    String newUserId = generateUserId();
    await updateUserIdInFirestore(newUserId);
  }

  runApp(MyAppLauncher());
}

Future<String> getCurrentUserId() async {
  try {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return user?.uid ?? '';
  } catch (e) {
    print("Erreur lors de la récupération de l'ID utilisateur: $e");
    return '';
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Stripe.publishableKey = 'your_publishable_key_here';
  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  } catch (e) {
    print("Erreur lors de l'initialisation de Firebase: $e");
    return;
  }

  await handleUserLogin();
}

class MyAppLauncher extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: getCurrentUserId(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            
            print(
                "Error ID : ${snapshot.error}");
            return const Directionality(
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Failed to get user ID'),
              ),
            );
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
            
            print("No User");
            return const Directionality(
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('No user ID available'),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            
            final userId = snapshot.data!;
            return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (context) => BalanceNotifier(userId)),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Cart()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeNotifier()),
              ],
              child: const MyApp(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeNotifier = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const SplashScree(),
      theme: lightMode,
      darkTheme: darkMode,
      themeMode: themeNotifier.currentTheme,
    );
  }
}

My CartPage:
TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      bool transactionSuccess =
                          true; // Simulating a successful transaction
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title:
                            Text(transactionSuccess ? 'Successful' : 'Pending'),
                        content: Text(transactionSuccess
                            ? 'Your transaction was successful.'
                            : 'Your transaction is pending.'),
                        actions: [
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              if (transactionSuccess) {
                                print(
                                    'Transaction was successful. Updating balance...');
                                Provider.of<BalanceNotifier>(context,
                                        listen: false)
                                    .updateBalance(totalAmount);

                                
                                value.clearCart();
                                _selectedPaymentMethod = null;
                                _confirmationNumberController.clear();

                                
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                  SnackBar(
                                    content: Text(
                                        'Your transaction was successful.'),
                                  ),
                                );
                              } else {
                                // Afficher un message d'erreur
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                  SnackBar(
                                    content:
                                        Text('Your transaction is pending.'),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                            child: const Text('OK'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('OK'),
              ),

My TransfertPage
Consumer<BalanceNotifier>(
                builder: (context, balanceNotifier, child) {
                  print('Balance in MyCard: ${balanceNotifier.balance}');
                  return MyCard(
                    balance: balanceNotifier.balance,
                    userId: widget.userId,
                    cardNumber: 123435647,
                    expiryMonth: 12,
                    expiryYear: 24,
                    color: Colors.grey[900]!,
                    status:
                        'Actived', // Change this line to get the actual status dynamically
                  );
                },
              ),

Firestore Rules
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      
    }
    
    match /transactions/{transaction} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
     // Autorisation pour la sous-collection 'transactions'
    match /users/{userId}/transactions/{transactionId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
        }
  }
}

Additional Information
Flutter 3.22.2 • channel stable
Provider: ^6.1.2
macOS Monterey Version 12.7.4

Goal:
When I press "OK" in the CartPage, I want the total amount to be updated in TransferPage (MyCard).
I've tried various solutions but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Try to add the type to the provider, like ChangeNotifierProvider<BalanceNotifier>(create: (context) => BalanceNotifier(userId)),.

Thank you for your suggestion. I applied the changes to the provider initialization syntax in main.dart as follows:
return MultiProvider(
providers: [
ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) => BalanceNotifier(userId),
),
ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) => Cart(),
),
ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) => ThemeNotifier(),
),
],
child: const MyApp(),
);
However, the issue still persists. Any further insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

As far as I see you have two MaterialApp in the widget tree, that can be problematic. Try to reorganise with one MaterialApp and put the MultiProvider as high as you need, even above MaterialApp.

I was running into an issue because I had two MaterialApp instances in my widget tree.
With Peter's awesome tip to check for multiple MaterialApp instances, I refactored my code to use just one MaterialApp. I moved my providers and MultiProvider usage to MyAppLauncher and simplified MyApp.
Big Thanks!
A huge shoutout to @PeterKoltai for pointing out the issue with having two MaterialApp instances. Your advice to reorganize with one MaterialApp and put the MultiProvider as high as needed was spot on and saved the day!

Good to hear! You are welcome.
